# CSS transform not working on firefox extension

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-addon, transform

I've been playing around with addon sdk to create extension that ie. could be used when drawing a line on image found from internet web site.

The extension works so that it extends the internet site's DOM with a few div-tags, which are mapped to css.

to create a line I've used CSS transform like this

```
fibotin.draw = function (event) {
    var currentPosX = event.clientX;
    var currentPosY = event.clientY;
    event.preventDefault();
    /* .... */
    if (drawSelection === "line") {
        var length = fibotin.calculateLineLength(currentPosX, currentPosY, drawObj.startPosX, drawObj.startPosY);
        var angle = fibotin.calculateAngle(currentPosX, currentPosY, drawObj.startPosX, drawObj.startPosY);
        var transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';

        drawObj.element.style.transform = transform;
        drawObj.element.style.width = length;
    }
```

and in CSS I've declared like this

```
#line{
transform-origin: 0 100%;
height: 2px; 
background: red; 
position: fixed;
z-index: 999999; 
cursor: move;
}
```

For some reason this code does not work on all site's. (ie. google.com)
But in some cases - on simpler site's - it works (www.stox.fi)

Does anyone have idea how to fix this so that it would work on all sites?

you can check how it work on my extension called Fibotin

Answer (score 0):

Set `position` to `relative` or `absolute`. That should make `transform`s work then. `fixed` should make it work. It's odd that it isn't, maybe there is something overriding this?

Comment: tnx for reply. I found the problem. drawObj.element.style.width needed to add +"px" .. so the line should then: drawObj.element.style.width = length+"px";

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution!